# Fast change of my ip/proxy in terminal for one command

Tags: bash, proxy, ip

I need to change my IP for one command in bash command line,
so I want use proxy (`123.123.123.123:8`0 format),
how can I do it?
For example if I write:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

I get my original IP, so how I can make it show proxy IP?

To be more specific, I need change my IP for `whois` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl (and some other command line utilities) use environment variables to get their proxy settings so you'd just run:

```
http_proxy=http://123.123.123.123:80/ curl http://ifconfig.me
```

But `whois` (the whole protocol, not just the command) doesn't work over HTTP; it's its own protocol running on port 43. **You can't readily proxy it with a standard HTTP proxy.**

If you want to proxy other protocols, you're going to have to look at a proper VPN or [something SOCKS-based like `proxychains`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62556/whois-over-ssh-via-specific-port).

Comment: Yes, I already saw it somewhere but it doesn't work for whois :(

Comment: @qlwik I've added a chunk about whois. It's not as simple, I'm afraid.

Comment: So it is possible use socks proxies?

Comment: Ok thanks, Your answer redirect me to the right solution about socks.